# How to remove a view from a LinearLayout without affecting the positions of the other children?

Tags: java, android, view, scrollview, android-linearlayout

I am trying to add/remove views to a LinearLayout inside a ScrollView.  I would like to remove/add views to the LinearLayout while it is scrolling for larger lists might blow memory and/or be slow.  Is there any way to remove a View from the LinearLayout without it affecting the position of its siblings?

When I call `linearLayout.removeChildAt(0)`, all of the views snap back one, making it really difficult to maintain a constant scrolling effect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By adding/subtracting the size of the removed View at position 0 to the parents padding, I effectively stopped the "chopping" effect when I was removing views.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if this is applicable for you(maybe u are aware of this already), but usually when there is a list of view which you have to show, instead of using scrollviews and adding/removing subviews yourself, you can make use of ListView in android.

Comment: In fact keeping lists of views efficient is the very purpose of ListView.

Comment: I was using ListView for an earlier prototype of what I'm currently implementing with the ScrollView.. just can't remember why I switched

Answer (score 0):

When you remove a view, replace it with a blank placeholder view of the same size as the removed view.

Comment: Then we would be using the same amount of views, otherwise I wouldn't be removing them.  Maybe mod the padding of the LinearLayout!